# How to send the body in wp_remote_post as "raw"?

Tags: rest-api, wp-remote-post

I'm not sure if I'm asking the right question, so here is the context.

I'm making a POST to an API (The api is to a Google Sheets Script - so there are some unusual limitations). When I use postman the data is returned in a json file. In order to get it to work in postman I have to send the parameters via the body and I have to select the raw option. Selecting any other option(i.e. x-www-form-urlencoded or form-data) results in an html error page.

I've followed the steps for wp_remote_post($api_url , $body ); in the WordPress documentation - but I'm getting the html error instead of the expected data.

How do I send the body as "raw" just like it's being sent in Postman?

UPDATE - To add code.

```
$api_url = 'https://script.google.com/macros/s/UNIQUE_KEYw/exec';
// $body = array(
//  "method"=>"GET",
//  "sheet"=>"date",
//  "key"=>"PASSWORD");

$body = ('{\n"method": "GET",\n"sheet": "date",\n"key": "PASSWORD"\n}');

$request =  wp_remote_post($api_url , array(
    'method'      => 'POST',
    'headers'     => ["Content-Type" => "raw"],
    'body'        => $body,
    'data_format' => 'body'
    )
                          );
```

The HTTP_Request2 snippet from postman that I'm trying to recreate.

```
<?php
require_once 'HTTP/Request2.php';
$request = new HTTP_Request2();
$request->setUrl('https://script.google.com/macros/s/UNIQUE_KEY/exec');
$request->setMethod(HTTP_Request2::METHOD_POST);
$request->setConfig(array(
  'follow_redirects' => TRUE
));
$request->setHeader(array(
  'Content-Type' => 'text/plain'
));
$request->setBody('{\n"method": "GET",\n"sheet": "date",\n"key": "PASSWORD"\n}');
try {
  $response = $request->send();
  if ($response->getStatus() == 200) {
    echo $response->getBody();
  }
  else {
    echo 'Unexpected HTTP status: ' . $response->getStatus() . ' ' .
    $response->getReasonPhrase();
  }
}
catch(HTTP_Request2_Exception $e) {
  echo 'Error: ' . $e->getMessage();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I got this one working, you have to pass the json_encoded array on the body parameter of the request.

```
 $customer_details = [
            'first_name' => $first_name,
            'last_name' => $last_name,
            'email' => $email,
        ];

        $customer_details['body'] = json_encode($customer_details);

        $customer = $api->createUpdateCustomer($customer_details);

public function createUpdateCustomer($customer_details) {
        $response = $this->apiCall( "2.0/customers", 'POST', $customer_details);
        $result = json_decode($response);
        return $result;
    }

public function apiCall($baseUrl = null, $method = 'GET', $args = array()) {
        if ( !is_null( $baseUrl ) ) {
            $url = $this->baseUrl . $baseUrl;
        }
        else {
            $url = $this->baseUrl;
        }

        // Populate the args for use in the wp_remote_request call
        $wp_args = array_merge($args, $this->args);
        $wp_args['method']  = $method;
        $wp_args['timeout'] = 30;        

        // Make the call and store the response in $res
        $res = wp_remote_request( $url, $wp_args );        

        // Check for success
        if ( ! is_wp_error( $res ) && ( 200 == $res['response']['code'] || 201 == $res['response']['code'] ) ) {
            return $res['body'];
        } else {
            throw new Exception( "API call didn't go well :(. Either VendHQ Connect Settings are incorrect or VendHQ server is not responding as expected." );
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to set `headers` to use `content-type: application/json`:

```php
$api_url = 'https://script.google.com/macros/s/UNIQUE_KEYw/exec';
$body = wp_json_encode( array(
    "method" => "GET",
    "sheet" => "date",
    "key" => "PASSWORD"
) );

wp_remote_post( $api_url, [
    'headers'   => [ 'Content-Type' => 'application/json' ],
    'body'       => $body,
    'data_format' => 'body'
] );
```

Comment: Ok I was trying text/plain. How would I format the body then? - I've updated the question with my code.

Comment: I updated based on the code you provided - you should be able to just use `json_encode()` on the body array you have commented out.  In WP there's `wp_json_encode()`.  Also you might mean to set headers to 'content-type': 'application/json'?

Comment: I spent some time on this, unfortunately I don't think it's working properly. I do think the request is being sent, but I think the request needs to be very specific. 

I've added the working HTTP_request2 snippet from Postman that I'm trying to recreate with WP to the original post.